# swapping infinite sum with the logarithm for the logarithm with the infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

Let $s$ be a complex number with $Re(s)>1$. We know by the Euler product theorem that $\Pi_{\text{primes},p}(1-1/p^s)^{-1}=\zeta(s)$.

In this case, how do we ensure that $$\sum_{\text{primes},p}\log(1-1/p^s)^{-1}=\log \zeta(s),$$ that is what condition precisely allows us to move the infinite sum inside the logarithm to get the RHS which is the logarithm of the infinite product over primes?

Answer (score 3):

Let $ s \in ( 1, \infty )  $ be real
and denote by  $ p _{ n} $ the $ n$th prime number. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \prod_{p}^{}  \!\left( 1 - \frac{1}{ p ^{ s}} \right)^{-1} 
    = \lim_{ n \to\infty} P _{ n} 
\end{aligned}
$$
for
$$
\begin{aligned}
P _{ n} = \prod_{k = 1}^{n}  \!\left( 1 - \frac{1}{ p _{ k}  ^{ s}}  \right)^{-1} 
.\end{aligned}
$$
Now
$$
\begin{aligned}
\ln\!\left( \zeta ( s) \right) 
= \ln\!\left( \lim_{n \to \infty } P _{ n} \right) 
= \lim_{ n \to\infty} \ln\!\left( P _{ n} \right) 
= \lim_{ n \to\infty} \sum_{ k = 1}^{ n} \ln\!\left( ( 1 - 1 / p _{ k} ^{ s})^{-1}  \right) 
\end{aligned}
$$
by continuity of the natural logarithm.
Notice that the lhs and rhs  analytically extended to complex $s $ with $ \text{Re}  \!\left( s\right) > 1$ so they must be equal on $ \text{Re}  \!\left( s\right) > 1$.

Comment: A few questions that may be obvious. What allows us to restrict $s$ to be real number and get the first limit over the finite product to get the infinite product? And for the rhs, for the limit of the sum of logarithms holomorphic don't we need uniform limit here? How can we guarantee that?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician the end of his answer explains why we can restrict $s$ to be a real number. the definition of an infinite product is the limit of the finite products. finally, it suffices to have local uniform convergence rather than uniform convergence.